# How to design a visit card using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing a visit card that looks like following:

```
Name Family                                     Image
Position
Phone
Address                               website

A short list of Product and services          small logo
```

My main issue is position of website and the image.
I need to put the website address next to the bottom left corner of the image.

As you can see the the image should start from the top right corner to where the website is.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/tjmrjwmj/2/)

**Code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"style="padding-right: 0; border-right: solid;">
                        <div  style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: red;">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-7">

                                    <p>Part 1</p>
                                    <p>Part 2</p>
                                    <p>Part 3</p>
                                    <p>Part 4</p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: bottom;">
                                    <div>Part 5</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                    <img height="100px" width="120px" style="float: right;"
                                        src="http://identityview.net/wp-content/themes/identityview/templates/Global-Business-single.jpg">

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9">Part 6</div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img height="60px" width="60px"
                                        src="http://identityview.net/wp-content/themes/identityview/templates/Global-Business-single.jpg"
                                        style="float: right;">
                                </div>

                            </div>


                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with it in JSFiddle and this was my quick solution.

```
                                <div class="col-md-1">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4" style="float:right;">
                                    <p style="display:inline;vertical-align:bottom;">Website</p>
                                    <img height="100px" width="120px"
                                        src="http://identityview.net/wp-content/themes/identityview/templates/Global-Business-single.jpg">

                                </div>
```

I updated the JSFiddle for you so you can see the solution in work.
http://jsfiddle.net/rc28avn0/1/